# mongo find operation returns an empty object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
db.collection("mscCollection").find(function (err, cur) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(cur))
})
```

When i run this it returns an empty object even though the collection contains documents and am able to find them using the shell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually a cursor object and not a empty object. Since you call JSON.stringify on it, it will remove all the functions from it and print it. A better way to inspect it is to just call console.log directly on it: `console.log(cur);`.

Using find method, if you want to get all the documents you have to call `cursor.toArray(callback)` method.

To get the cursor, either you register a callback for find method, or use find result(one of them only. If a callback is registered nothing is returned):

Either this:

```
collection.find().toArray(function (err, docs) {
  console.log(err, docs);
});
```

Or this:

```
collection.find(function (err, cursor) {
  cursor.toArray(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(err, docs);
  });
});
```

Comment: It works but an error is returned in the console :[MongoError: Connection Closed By Application] name: 'MongoError'.   

am not calling db.close() anywhere

Comment: What did you do exactly? That happens when an error is thrown on db.open callback, and error will be thrown when you pass a callback to  find but use it's return value. As I said you can do only one of the styles above, you can't mix.

Answer (score 0):

The function signature is available here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find

You need to do:

```
db.mscCollection.find({}).forEach(function (obj) {  printjson(obj) })
```

You need to find all documents using `{}` and then iterate over the result set using `forEach`

Comment: from the documentation: To return all documents in a collection, omit this parameter or pass an empty document ({})

Comment: This function is for the mongo shell and not node.js mongo driver, as it was tagged in the question, so it's not really useful here.